# Conditional loading of mix css in blade header blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I would like to define `header.blade.php` which then will be included in:

- `index.blade.php`
- `dashboard.blade.php`
- `basic.blade.php`
- `advanced.blade.php`

and I would like to load different mix CSS styles depending on which blade view is this `header.blade.php` view included in currently I am loading all the styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/all.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/dashboard.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/basic.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/advanced.css') }}" />
```

But I would like to add condition "if included from `dashboard.blade.php` load only `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/all.css') }}" />` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/dashboard.css') }}" />`
",...

Is that something that can be accomplished in blade views in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the @yield directive. It allows pages that include a layout to define their own different implementations of the same section.

https://laravel.io/forum/09-02-2014-using-section-and-yield